# pandas.read_excel() on strangley formatted excel tables

Tags: python, pandas

Would pandas.read_excel() read something like this?

As you can see, there's a few lines of text before and after the table.

I cannot manually delete those unwanted lines of text.

[image]

Comment: `read_excel` has some arguments such as `skiprows` and `usecols` which might be what you want. Reference here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html

Answer (score 3):

you can try below code

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("/Users/manoj/demo.csv",  encoding='utf-8', skiprows=5)
```

Refer Panda [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv)

Comment: what about the rows underneath?

Comment: you can skip unwanted rows and drop column using the above method.

Answer (score 0):

if pandas skip rows doesn't work;

you could use xlsxwriter or some other xlsx engine to read it into an array then import that array into a pandas dataframe

Comment: I'm using xlrd which is doing the job fine but I wondered using pandas would be a better option for the future

Comment: definitely depends on what you need it for, I find that the pandas to_excel and read_excel functions to be quite slow (I haven't done an analysis, just was having a lot of issues with how long it took) and also as you can tell its pretty strict with how it imports into a dataframe which can be annoying